# Connecting a Client to Multiple Servers in Java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I want a client to connect to more than one server. i.e. I want my client to send a number to `server1` which squares the number and echoes it back to the client.  However I want the client to then send this squared number to a second server listening on a different port.

I'm not sure how to implement this functionality, could I do this through threads or would I just open a second socket to `server2`?

Here is the code for my client.

```
import java.io.*;

import java.net.*;

public class ClientA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String serverhost = "localhost";
    int serverport = 6789;

        Socket clientSocket = null;  
        DataOutputStream os = null;
        BufferedReader is = null;

   try {
            clientSocket = new Socket(serverhost, serverport);
            os = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + serverhost);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: " + serverhost);
        } //end try

if (clientSocket == null || os == null || is == null) {
        System.err.println( "An error has occured, please restart." );
        return;
    } //end if

    try {
        while ( true ) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String keyboardInput = br.readLine();
        os.writeBytes( keyboardInput + "\n" );

        int n = Integer.parseInt( keyboardInput );
        if ( n == 0 ) {
            break;
        }

        String responseLine = is.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server returns its square as: " + responseLine);
        }

        os.close();
        is.close();
        clientSocket.close();   
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Trying to connect to unknown host: " + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
    } //end try
    } //end main
} //end class
```

Comment: Do you need to maintain the connection to the first server after you received the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the info you've given, I don't see the need to make it a multi-threaded application as you're only sending (i.e. not receiving) data to the second server when you receive a reply from the first server. Just set up a second socket to the other address and send the data when you get it from the first server.

Comment: However if I do need to receive information from the second server? do i need to make it multithreaded then? Or can I just close the socket to the first server and open a socket to the second?

Comment: @user1896168 You don't even need to close that socket, you can still receive info from the second socket, it's just that you won't be able to send new data to the first server (I see you have a while true loop) until you're done communicating with the second socket so that is a delay. If the delay is a problem, threads would be prefferable.